# How to calculate time in android .?

Tags: android, timer

I want to calculate time after a button pressed ,so that i can keep track that this much has been passed.I have search it and find that android timer can do that but i couldn't get any useful answer for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At what point did you want it to stop? You are lacking details.

Comment: look up [System.currentTimeMillis](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On start button press:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

On update/end button press:

```
long runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

Comment: A notice for who might see this post: System.currentTimeMillis() might change when user changes the 'Date and Time' in his device settings.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to calculate time difference between two events then you can use
`System.currentTimeMillis();`.